# What is the best way to use bootstrap 3 (grid)) in yii 1.1?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I would like to use bootstrap 3 (grid) in yiii. Especially with CGridView and the other yii widgets.

I would really like to be able to apply classes like '.col-sm-4'.

So, on base of what we know so far, what is the best way to use bootstrap 3 (grid) with yii 1.1(CGridView)?

Thanks

Comment: Not to be the hater, but bootstrap 3 is pretty much [EOL](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22343), as is [Yii 1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii#Version_history)

Comment: I don't mind working with bootstrap 4 and yii 1.1 if that is possible. It's easy with general features but i guess not with the CGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Set `itemCssClass` property of CGridView widget with Boostrap table classes.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<?php
...
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'my-model-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed'
));
...
?>
</div>
```

The `.table-responsive` class creates a responsive table. The table will then scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference

The `.table` class adds basic styling to a table.

The `.table-striped` class adds zebra-stripes to a table.

The `.table-bordered` class adds borders on all sides of the table and cells.

The `.table-hover` class adds a hover effect (grey background color) on table rows.

The .`table-condensed` class makes a table more compact by cutting cell padding in half.

[Boostrap Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp)